# Evaluate $\int z ds $ over the curve $x=y=z^2$ from $(1,1,1)$ to $(4,4,2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Let r denote the path $x=y=z^2$ from $(1,1,1)$ to $(4,4,2)$. Evaluate
$$\int_rz ds.$$

I am not sure where to even begin on this one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Kindly have a look at [Line Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an integral is called the line integral of a scalar field. You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) for some introduction. Here $ds$ is the infinitesimal of the arc length. In the 3-dimensional space we have $ds = dz\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dz})^2+(\frac{dy}{dz})^2+1}$. By the relationship of $x,y,z$ in this problem $\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dx}{dz} = 2z$, so we have $ds = dz\sqrt{8z^2 + 1}$. Therefore the original integral is
$$
\int_r zds = \int_1^2 z\sqrt{8z^2 + 1}dz \overset{t=z^2}{=} \frac{1}{2}\int_1^4\sqrt{8t+1}dt = \frac{1}{24}[(8t+1)^{3/2}]^4_1 = \frac{1}{24}(33^{3/2}-27).
$$

Comment: Thanks! I've been pulling my hair out trying to find material on this but because I didn't know that this was a special case of line integrals I couldn't find anything. Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome :)